# Why do some open-source Linux software packages costs?

Tags: linux, opensource-projects

I've been researching on Internet that open-source are free, but I found a bit contradicting fact that there are some packages which are commercial like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DaDaBIK).

I too have used some tools like Metasploit which ask for license. Is a product developed by modification of a open-source can be commercial? I'm totally confused!

Comment: The example you link to *is not* open source. If the software is open source, you generally pay for support or premium features that are then released to the community after some period of time.

Comment: You are confusing free software with freeware. Free software refers to freedom, while freeware to the price. Read http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.html and http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_models_for_open-source_software See here @jsonwryan

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about commercialization and licensing.

Comment: This is not off-topic, this is my doubt on why do they commercialize open-source products. Indeed it is related to UNIX and Linux. IMO!

Comment: Find out what is Free Software https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html (Freedom not price, including the freedom to sell copies). Then realise that most software that is Open Source is Free Software and vice versa. Then realise that the term Open Source is often missuses, and confused, often on purpose, by proprietary developers (proprietary is the opposite of free, not commercial as Free Software can be commercial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open source means that the source is open: available to look at.

That does not influence the **copyright** and the **license**. The copyright holder can of course change the license (as with DaDaBIK in June 2012). The license of the software also determines whether derivatives are allowed and can be commercial or not.

Comment: Hmm, I got it, so can I sell a product which is a modified version of an open-source?

Comment: Not always. You really have to read the license under which the software is supplied, or search for an overview of licenses that explains it.

Comment: @Ruban Savvy that depends on what license the code you are modifying has.

Comment: so which license has the right to sell and which doesn't?

Comment: You can /always/ sell, but most open source licenses require you to also offer to make the source freely available on request if you do so.

Comment: @zelda you are wrong in almost every way: Paragraph 1 this is the most common misunderstanding of Open Source, and why I like the term Free Software (Freedom not price); Paragraph 2a it is all about the licence and copyright (like 100% about the licence and copyright);

Comment: @zelda Paragraph 2b the licence must allow commercial distribution to qualify as open source (from paragraph 1 of open source definition: The license shall not restrict any party from selling or giving away the software as a component of an aggregate software distribution containing programs from several different sources. The license shall not require a royalty or other fee for such sale. )